# Insert some text after Nth matching pattern using sed

Tags: sed, matching

How can I do so? I have multiple e.g. foobar patterns in my file, how can I add after e.g. the 4th one some_text?

Comment: so you want to do the insert/replace on nth occurrence of the whole file? for example. one line could have any number of "foobar"

Comment: @kent: no each line contains just one foobar, but the whole file contains many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\(foobar\)/\1\nsome_text/4' inputfile
```

For the input:

```
$ cat inputfile
line
foobar
foobar
foobar
line
foobar
line
foobar
line
foobar
line
```

This would generate

```
$ sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\(foobar\)/\1\nsome_text/4' inputfile
line
foobar
foobar
foobar
line
foobar
some_text
line
foobar
line
foobar
line
```

Use `-e` on FreeBSD:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\(foobar\)/\1\nsome_text/4' inputfile
```

Comment: this error:
sed: 1: ":a;$!{N;ba};s/\(foobar\ ...": unused label 'a;$!{N;ba};s/\(foobar\)/\1\nsome_text/4'

Comment: Read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) and then ask what you didn't follow.

Comment: what should I do in case of inserting multiple lines with \n at the end and also / included?

Comment: `sed -e :a -e '$!N' -e '$!ba' -e 's#\(foobar\)#\1\nsome_text\nmore_text_on_new_line_with_/_character#4' inputfile`

Answer (score 1):

an awk version:

```
 awk '/foo/{x++} x==4{sub(/foo/,"&some_text")}1' file
```

example:

```
kent$  cat file
foo
foo
trash
foo
trash
foo
foo
foo

kent$  awk '/foo/{x++} x==4{sub(/foo/,"&some_text")}1' file
foo
foo
trash
foo
trash
foosome_text
foo
foo
```